# Zend Lucene is under processing now... crashed my website

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

```
{Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception} Index is under processing now
```

This is what i get in my error log which makes crash the 50% of my website.
What should i do to fix that please ?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean a 500 error, there is an `error.log` that should contain a description of what went wrong.

Comment: {Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception} Index is under processing now is only what i get in my error.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i deleted the whole index and put the chmod777 on the entire folders+subfolders index and it fixed the problem.